# Windows phone creating custom objects to columns?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, sql-server-ce, create-table

as the question title says, I am trying to map a custom object to a db column on windows phone how can I do this? the exception I am getting: "Unable to determine SQL type for 'Layer'."

layer is a custom object, what is the correct way to store this, can someone please provide me with a example. thank you

code:

...

```
[Table]
    public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    {
        #region ID
        //not autogenerated, this is from the client
        private String _id;

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = false, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public String Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                if (_id != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("id");
                    _id = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("id");
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

 #region Product Layer
        private Layer _productlayer;

        [Column]
        public Layer ProductLayer
        {
            get { return _productlayer; }
            set
            {
                if (_productlayer != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("ProductLayer");
                    _productlayer = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductLayer");
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
```

....

```
 public class Layer
{
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string des { get; set; }
    public string pos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this, unless you store a serialized version in a byte[] (image) column

Comment: not sure what you meen, can you maybe give a example please?